# Android: saving to getExternalPublicStorageDirectory and displaying in gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, gallery

So I was following the android tutorial Capture (with camera intent) Simply

In the tutorial it says specifically to use the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory call when (creating the image "File") saving pictures, however in their example they use getExternalStorageDirectory. Basically its a "do as i say not as i do" example.

So I tried using the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory all sort of errors come up. I eventually got it to work and i can see these files really do exist via ADB shell. For the life of me I can't get them to show up in the gallery. using the media scanner connection to scan the file doesn't seem to do the trick. Does anyone know how to get the file to show up in the gallery?

code snippets:

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {    // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new 
        SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File pictureDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);


        // if the file does not exist, then create the file.
        if(!pictureDir.exists())
        {
            pictureDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                pictureDir      /* directory */
        );

        boolean exists = image.exists();

        this.currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent()
    {

    verifyStoragePermissions(this);
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // i believe this is checking if the activity exists.
        if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        {
            File imageFile = null;

            try
            {
                imageFile = createImageFile();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.i("sf", e.getMessage());
                Log.i("sf",e.getCause().getMessage());
            }

            if(imageFile != null)
            {
                imageFile.toURI();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFile.toURI());
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

       private void addGalleryPic() throws IOException {
           Intent mediaScanIntent = new 
           Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
           File f = new File(this.currentPhotoPath);

           if(f.exists())
           {
               Log.i("sdf", f.getAbsolutePath() + " exists");

           }

           MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                   new String[]{currentPhotoPath}, null,
                   new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                       public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                           String p = uri.getPath();
                           Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                           Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                       }
                   });
       }
```

Comment: "using the media scanner connection to scan the file doesn't seem to do the trick" -- it should. However, I do not see where you are calling `addGalleryPic()`.

Comment: I didn't include it as it would be assumed i did that in the onActivityResult override. @CommonsWare

Comment: Then perhaps `currentPhotoPath` is `null`, as I do not see how you are saving it in the saved instance state `Bundle`, and your process might be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground.

Comment: its not null i just didn't include that part of the code. I only included the calls pertaining to what my issue is.]

Answer (score 0):

Try saving them to internal storage as the phone should pick up any photos in the internal storage.

Hope it helps!